# How to sync users of wordpress database to codeigniter database

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter-3

does anybody have some solution, if i am running wordpress and codeigniter on same VPS Server but having different database. is it possible the users who register on wordpress, can also login to codeigniter application user area, is it possible to sync wordpress user table with codeigniter user table or any other solutions for this?

Comment: You can use the [`user_register`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) hook to get the data of the user after its creation and then do a request to a function that registers users IN your CodeaIgniter application. The same when the password is reset using [`after_password_reset`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_password_reset/) or [`profile_update`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update) when the profile is changed.

Comment: @Mithc - Buddy, Can you help me with sample code, i am not getting it.

Comment: Do you use Community Auth for account management in your CodeIgniter? So I can write something more specific :)